# Is there a way to use mapped types while keeping methods an instance method and not a property?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

```ts
interface A {
  x(): void
}

// this is the same as Pick<A, keyof A>
type B = {[K in keyof A]: A[K]}
```

In the above example, `A` is `{x(): void}` and `B` is `{x: () => void}`. Is there a way to use mapped types while keeping `x` as an instance method and not a property?

---

I want it to be a method because of things like this:

```ts
declare const a: new () => A
declare const b: new () => B

class C extends a {
  // no error
  x() {}
}

class D extends b {
  // Class 'B' defines instance member property 'x',
  // but extended class 'D' defines it as instance member function.
  x() {}
//~
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QDwAoBKALmQDcB7YAEywF8ssB6F5MAC2AGdleOnFDzgBbFHD4AFYAgDWAHlQAaZHIgBPKjDQA+LGA0AHFACFkAXkzIA2gGl+INZu1oAuuVT23yJlloQCAA2cFAoCFQgPGDIcOQgEADuyCSWumj+gSFhyBFRMQBG8UkpxGnIpszBknwAwsgQ+JAgtHxwmDh4RGUYTH7VPHwAIg1NEC18BR14BKm9jFhAA)

Comment: You are on pretty tricky territory. You can probably try submitting a bug to the compiler team. It appears that `B['x']` is sometimes treated as a method. For instance it presents argument covariance, instead of contravariance. (see [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oA8AUAjAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmUAPlJQK4C2uEpAlIQIaUgoAvihQB6UVGAALckSizJU6ER4toPOQAVyAYwDWAHhgAaKHoggA9gDNYAPhShIUAEIJkUANoBpeZTMWNrAAuoQwPsFQwo7g0ADq5NKapJZg7qgYWIR4hCQUNPSMrOxcCHZQfALRADYQwFmu6Q05xGRU1JxlyIJRANwotfUghAlJKWmISM0ErfkdXVM9gv1AA))

Comment: Also if you investigate `(new b).x` it says it's a method, but if you investigate `B`, it looks like a property.

Comment: You don't have to submit an issue; there's an existing one: [microsoft/TypeScript#27689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27689).  If you want to see this happen you might want to give it a  or explain your use case.